# How to collect names in a loop then use StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, while-loop

Have been up for hours trying to figure out how to add in these in a string array using user input and StringBuilder.
I have to in a loop collect names from user input (scanner).
when they enter a blank name stop looping. Then iterate over the attendee list to create the output string using StringBuilder.
only 1 name = Name .
2 names = Name 1 and name 2 . more then 2 names = name 1, name2, and name 3 . output should exactly match the way these are formatted with spaces, commas, and the "and".

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("You have invited: ");

     System.out.println("enter names.");
     String attendee = keyboard.nextLine();
     // receiving input

     while (attendee != "") {
         sb.append(attendee);
         if (attendee == "") break;
     }

     System.out.println(sb);

     for (int i = 0; i > sb.length(); i++) {

         if (i == 0) {
             keyboard.nextLine(); //consuming the <enter> from input above
             sb.append(keyboard.nextLine());
             i++;
         } else if (i == 1) {
             sb.append(keyboard.nextLine() + " and " + keyboard.nextLine());
             System.out.println(sb);
         } else if (i > 1) {
             sb.append(keyboard.nextLine() + ", " + keyboard.nextLine() + ", and " + keyboard.nextLine());
             System.out.println(sb);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: please [edit], share the actual output and the expected output

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of errors in your code

- you don't ask again in the `while` loop for a new value, so either you never get in (first empty string) or never get out (first not empty) also that isn't how you compare a string, that is an object, use `.equals()`
- you may not call `keyboard.nextLine()` (getting input) in the loop where you build the output
- names shouldn't be joined in the StringBuilder, then how would you build the output

---

So, make a nice loop that populates a list of String, then nicely concatenate the different parts to make the output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.print("enter name: ");
    String attendee = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (!attendee.equals("")) {
        names.add(attendee);
        System.out.print("enter name: ");
        attendee = keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(namesToString(names));
}

static String namesToString(List<String> names) {
    List<String> firsts = names.subList(0, names.size() - 1);
    String last = names.get(names.size() - 1);

    if (names.size() == 1)
        return "You have invited: " + last;

    return "You have invited: " + String.join(", ", firsts) + " and " + last;
}
```

```
enter name: Patrick
enter name: Pierre
enter name: James
enter name: John
enter name:
You have invited: Patrick, Pierre, James and John
```

---

Full possibilities of outputs

```
System.out.println(namesToString(Arrays.asList("pierre")));
// You have invited: pierre
System.out.println(namesToString(Arrays.asList("pierre", "jean")));
// You have invited: pierre and jean
System.out.println(namesToString(Arrays.asList("pierre", "jean", "eude")));
// You have invited: pierre, jean and eude
System.out.println(namesToString(Arrays.asList("pierre", "jean", "eude", "john", "james")));
// You have invited: pierre, jean, eude, john and james
```